# Is it possible to do Modpath7 particle tracking between a child and parent mf6 model using the exchange function with Flopy

Tags: python, flopy

I have good results running particle tracking with modpath7 on a modflow6 model using a structured grid.

But atm I am running a nested model with an outer and an inner modflow6 flow model and I can only seem to run modpath on either my "childGWF" or my "parentGWF" and not the exchangemodel.

Since the exchangemodel contains two different grids I dont really see how I would define the particles either.

Is there a solution or example doing this somewhere? I  have a situation where the particle would go from parent throught child model and end in the parent model and one where it would start in the parent model and the sink is in the child model.

I have so far "solved" it by using a simpler model with one grid for the particle tracking.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar issue myself. I do not think there is a good solution. Here is what I am doing:

1. Specify "PRINT_FLOWS" in the exchange file(s)
2. Convert the exchange flows printed in the mfsim.lst to wells and rerun each model separately with the new "exchange wells" to match the nested model head/flow distributions
3. Start MP7 in the appropriate model
4. Use the MP7 endpoints as you your start points in the other model(s)